# Ui select is not getting focused on click of tab key

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I'm using angular js 1.5, and this is the first time I'm using ui-select, and I'm facing many issues which I didn't find when I was trying them in plunker. It opens on first click but doesn't close on second click. It doesn't get focus when I click on tab key. These are the two bugs I'm facing. Can someone please help me.

Comment: I think you're not alone - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1592 check if the other bug was reported, and if not - create a plunker with the same angularjs version that you're using and see what happens - if you see the bug on plunker then you should report it to the developers of the plugin